# C++ Visual Studio Fatal Error C1002 with Glut

Tags: c++, freeglut

But my code making this problem when i run.

Actually two errors i fixed error.
But the C1002 error still remains.

What i tried:
i try to split my code recommentded on microsoft site 
I not try to smaller expressions beacuse i dont know how to smaller the expressions so.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/fatal-error-c1002?view=vs-2019

i used /Zm2000 to increase heap memory doesnt even helped and does nothing to error.

How i can fix it.

```
 #include "glut.h"
    #include "MetroFusion.h"

int EGrassMap[24530][25630] = { //our fur map
    {1,1,1,1},
    {1,1,1,1},
    {1,1,1,1},
    {1,1,1,1},
    {1,1,1,1}
};


void fur_obj(float xe,float ye,float ze,float heightc) {
    glTranslatef(xe, ye, ze);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glColor3f(0.498, 1.000, 0.000);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
    glColor3f(0.000, 1.000, 0.498);
    glVertex3f(0, heightc, 0);
    glEnd();
}
void grass(float x,float y,float z,float height,int grassmap[24530][25630]) {
    int animate;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++)
        {
            if (grassmap[i][j] == 1) {
                glPushMatrix();
                glRotatef(animate, animate, 0, 0);

            fur_obj(-j,i,0,height);
            glPopMatrix();
            }else {

                glPushMatrix();
                glPopMatrix();
            }
        }
    }

    if (animate > 160.0) {
        animate = 140;

    }
    if (animate < 150.0) {
        animate += 0.1;
    }


}
```

Metro Fusion .h:

```
#pragma once
#ifdef IEDXMetroFusion
#define IEDXMetroFusion_API__declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define IEDXMetroFusion_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
extern "C" IEDXMetroFusion_API int EGrassMap[24530][25630];
extern "C" IEDXMetroFusion_API void fur_obj(float xe, float ye, float ze, float heightc);
extern "C" IEDXMetroFusion_API  void grass(float x, float y, float z, float height, int grassmap[24530][25630]);
extern "C" IEDXMetroFusion_API int animate;
```

Compiler output:
1>------ Derleme başladı: Proje: IEDX.MetroFusion, Yapılandırma: Release Win32 ------
1>dllmain.cpp
1>IEDX.MetroFusion.cpp
1>c:\users\casper\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\iedx.metrofusion\iedx.metrofusion\iedx.metrofusion.cpp(6): warning C4273: 'EGrassMap': tutarsız dll bağlaması
1>c:\users\casper\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\iedx.metrofusion\iedx.metrofusion\metrofusion.h(7): note: önceki 'EGrassMap' tanımına bakın
1>c:\users\casper\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\iedx.metrofusion\iedx.metrofusion\iedx.metrofusion.cpp(15): warning C4273: 'fur_obj': tutarsız dll bağlaması
1>c:\users\casper\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\iedx.metrofusion\iedx.metrofusion\metrofusion.h(8): note: önceki 'fur_obj' tanımına bakın
1>c:\users\casper\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\iedx.metrofusion\iedx.metrofusion\iedx.metrofusion.cpp(24): warning C4273: 'grass': tutarsız dll bağlaması
1>c:\users\casper\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\iedx.metrofusion\iedx.metrofusion\metrofusion.h(9): note: önceki 'grass' tanımına bakın
1>Kod Üretiliyor...
1>C:\Users\casper\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\IEDX.MetroFusion\IEDX.MetroFusion\IEDX.MetroFusion.cpp : fatal error C1002: 2. geçişte derleyicide yığın tükendi
1>"IEDX.MetroFusion.vcxproj" projesini oluşturma tamamlandı -- BAŞARISIZ OLDU.
========== Oluşturma: 0 başarılı, 1 başarısız, 0 güncel, 0 atlandı ==========

the compiler output bit messy beacuse i using Turkish version of visual studio

Note : I DISABLED PRECOMPILED HEADER BEACUSE PRECOMPILED HEADER MAKING ERRORS

Comment: Why do you have that huge array (initialized with just 20 values) on the first place?

Comment: its for grass map

Comment: the code needed to create a grass map in game engine

Comment: someone can help me abound this thing

Comment: they are not importran just look my code dont look the array

Comment: i fixed it changing the array